# Sort by category and then date?

Tags: posts, loop, sort

I'll try to be as clear as possible. My Wordpress site has multiple custom categories and posts types all which need to be displayed on the home page blogroll. But I need the first post on the homepage always to be the most recent post from a specific category.

For example the story at the top of the page will always be the latest "hot-dog" category; and below it; sorted chronologically are more "hot-dogs" mixed with "hamburger" and "nachos"

How would  I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a 2 *loops* in your template file with [wp_query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).  Check the codex page for the correct parameters

Comment: I can't seem to get a category filter to work on my first loop '  <?php query_posts('showposts=1&tag=34'); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>'